# Two (almost) identical pieces of code produce separate results

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have been working on a little MVC project to assist in my self-learning and I have come across an issue that completely baffled me. I made a blog section in this MVC-ish system and pulled user permissions from an ACL with no problem whatsoever.
I moved onto creating a member section and as soon as i added any permissions checking I get the following error from Chrome:

> No data received
>   Unable to load the web page because the server sent no data.
>   Here are some suggestions:
>   Reload this web page later.
>   Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

I thought it was weird, so I double checked my error logs and nothing had shown up. So I decided to copy and paste the working blog code into the member file, reloaded and i got the EXACT same error, the only difference between the two files right now is the file name and the class name.
Here is the Blog code:

```
<?php
class blog extends frontController {
    public $model;
    public $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->model = $this->autoload_model();
        $this->user  = $this->load_user();
        $this->user->getUserRoles();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //Will only list the latest post ;)
        if(!$this->user->hasPermission('blog_access'))
        {
            $array = $this->model->list_posts();

            if(empty($array))
            {
                $this->variables(array(
                    'site_title' => 'View Blog Posts',
                    'post_title' => 'Sorry but there are no posts to display'
                ));
            } else {
                $this->variables(array(
                    'site_title' => 'View Blog Posts',
                    'list'       => $array[0],
                    'post_title' => $array[0]['entry_title'],
                    'link'       => str_replace(' ', '_',$array[0]['entry_title']),
                ));
            }
        } else {
            $this->variables(array(
                'site_title' => 'Error :: Design Develop Realize',
                'body'       => 'Sorry, but you do not have permission to access this',
            ));
        }

        $this->parse('blog/list', $this->toParse);
    }
```

This is the member file:

```
<?php

class member extends frontController {
    public $model;
    public $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->model = $this->autoload_model();
        $this->user  = $this->load_user();
        $this->user->getUserRoles();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //Will only list the latest post ;)
        if(!$this->user->hasPermission('blog_access'))
        {
            //$array = $this->model->list_posts();

            if(empty($array))
            {
                $this->variables(array(
                    'site_title' => 'Design Develop Realize :: View Blog Posts',
                    'post_title' => 'Sorry but there are no posts to display'
                ));
            } else {
                $this->variables(array(
                    'site_title' => 'Design Develop Realize :: View Blog Posts',
                    'list'       => $array[0],
                    'post_title' => $array[0]['entry_title'],
                    'link'       => str_replace(' ', '_',$array[0]['entry_title']),
                ));
            }
        } else {
            $this->variables(array(
                'site_title' => 'Error :: Design Develop Realize',
                'body'       => 'Sorry, but you do not have permission to access this',
            ));
        }

        $this->parse('blog/list', $this->toParse);
    }
```

In the member class, if I comment out `$this->user  = $this->load_user();` then the error disappears!!!
Just for reference here is that function:

```
protected function load_user()
{
    if(!$this->loader->loaded['acl'])
    {
        $this->loader->loadCore('acl');
    }

    return $this->loader->loaded['acl'];
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated as I am stumped!

PS yes I do have error reporting set to cover everything and no it does not log anything!

**EDIT:** Because all files go through index.php I have placed the error reporting there:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('date.timezone', "Europe/London");

require_once('system/library/loader.php');

$loader = new loader();
$loader->loadCore(array('frontController', 'routing'));
```

**EDIT 2:** loadCore() is below

```
public function loadCore($toLoad, $params = false)
{
    //important task first, check if it is more then 1 or not
    if(is_array($toLoad))
    {
        //more then one so lets go to the task!
        foreach($toLoad as $file)
        {
            if(file_exists('system/library/' . $file . '.php'))
            {
                require_once('system/library/' . $file . '.php');

                if($params)
                {
                    $this->loaded[$file] = new $file($params);
                } else {
                    $this->loaded[$file] = new $file;
                }
            } else {
                trigger_error("Core File $file does not exist");
            }
        }
    } else {
        //Phew, less work, it is only one!
        if(file_exists('system/library/' . $toLoad . '.php'))
        {
            require_once('system/library/' . $toLoad . '.php');

            if($params)
            {
                echo(__LINE__); exit;
                $this->loaded[$toLoad] = new $toLoad($params);
            } else {
                $this->loaded[$toLoad] = new $toLoad;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**: I modified loadCore so that if it was the acl being called it would use a try...catch() and that has not helped as it will not display an error just the same chrome and IE pages

**Update 2**: I have spoken with my host and it seems that everytime this error occurs, apache logs the following (not sure why I cannot see it in my copy of the logs!)

> [Wed Feb 22 08:07:11 2012] [error] [client 93.97.245.13] Premature end
>   of script headers: index.php

Comment: Can you show how you have set error reporting and where? Which logs are you looking at? Because stuff like this should absolutely leave a trace somewhere

Comment: I have updated the Question to show Pekka

Comment: Can you try putting the error_reporting line right in front of the offending call to rule out it is being set to "quiet" elsewhere? And can you specify which logs are you looking at?

Comment: Have done that now at the top of the offending class, inside the offending call's function and just before the call with no change to my luck :( . As for the logs, I have looked in apache's error logs as they are the only ones that have ever shown issues.

Comment: Strange. What do the access logs contain when you make such a request that gets terminated without data?

Comment: access.log says: 192.168.75.1 - - [14/Feb/2012:20:03:37 +0000] "GET /member HTTP/1.1" 200 558 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.46 Safari/535.11"

Comment: are you sure that is a *failed* request? Because the log entry claims it sent 558 bytes. Also, if you are in the UK, is that really a recent entry? It says yesterday night 8pm

Comment: Which is weird as that means it hasn't logged any access attempts since last night (I have tried about 10 times today)

Comment: strange - maybe it's logging to another location?

Comment: Checked, Apache is setup to log to that location only

Comment: I see error_reporting is set, but is `display_errors` definitely on? I see you also haven't used `error_log`, have you tried using it? As a last resort have you tried placing `echo`s or `die`s throughout the code with unique outputs to trace how far it is getting before it is failing? Why don't you use xdebug and actually step through the code a line at a time?

Comment: Hi Leigh, yes I have tried all of that except error_log. I havent used xdebug before but I will certainly look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Premature end of script headers"** are internal server errors. Which generally occurs when script breaks and does not send any HTTP headers before send the error messages. There might be several causes to this.

- One might be output buffering. May be the server you are using buffers the output by default. I will suggest turning off the `output_buffering` using `output_buffering = off` on `php.ini` <sup>[[docs here]](http://de.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering)</sup>.
- Make sure you are sending correct HTTP headers also

  > print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

There are few more suggestion on [this link](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=24447).
To learn more about this error, [go here](http://htmlfixit.com/cgi-tutes/tutorial_Common_Web_dev_error_messages_and_what_they_mean.php#premature).

Hope it helps

Comment: It hasnt fixed it completely but has solved another issue that i did not know about so thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have commented out

**//$array = $this->model->list_posts();**

So now array is null and you are trying to use

**'list'       => $array[0],
'post_title' => $array[0]['entry_title'],**

which definitely will generate an error.

EDIT:-

I see you have

`'body' => 'Sorry, but you do not have permission to access this' , )); }`

That is in second else which is a syntax error. and generates an output. If you have enabled, compress output in CI, that will cause this error.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it is the same with the line commented out or not, I have updated the OP with a new log result from apache

Comment: `'body'       => 'Sorry, but you do not have permission to access this' ,
            ));
        }`

The comma at end means, its expecting another element in array. But am not sure if it is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested in seeing what's inside the loadCore function.

Have you used [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) anywhere? It might help shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I see an `echo(__LINE__); exit;` in loadCore. Part of your testing?

Comment: I assume it isn't printing? Shouldn't it be in the else code block since in the other code, you are calling it without defined $params?

Comment: I need to take it all out, it all is working fine UNTIL the call loadCore for the ACL

Comment: yes it works in the blog class, both the blog and the member where the issue happens call the same frontController which contains the load_user function

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested this page in different browsers?  Googled your error, and it's indicating that it may be chrome specific?

Your statement that commenting out the loadCore('acl') is interesting, so obviously I would start there.  You're sure that it is getting the system/library/acl.php page via the loader?  Aka, it is triggering that line 2 below the exit in loadCore()?  var_dump the return imo to make sure you're getting the object.

Comment: Yes, as stated I have tried different browsers, I have var_dumped and it is fetching the file properly as it is working in one php file but not in the other

Answer (score 0):

First of all. This error is produced when your server disconnect before it send any data. 
A few suggestions.

- your code is broken and let crash the application
- your error logging should be enhanced by NOTICES
- write tests to check every part
- u should enable and use a debugger (zend_debugger, xdebug)
- post a few more connection infos (e.g. wget -O - --debug 'url')

There is/was a special chrome issue for that problem
http://www.google.pl/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3aa7b40eb01a95c8&hl=en#fid_3aa7b40eb01a95c80004ae797939c267

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking whether there are any blank lines before the  tags.

What file names are you using?, are there any conventions you have to follow to fit a framework you might be using?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is a server problem and not a code problem?

[This thread](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/premature-end-script-headers-index-php-error-500-a-138273.html) suggests that the server error you are seeing (500 premature end to headers) could be the result of Apache logs that are too full and need to be rotated. However it really could be anything - it seems to suggest simply that the script returns no output at all to the browser.

The other thing I'd check is file permissions, and the functioning of the include_once and file_exists in the loadCore method, as that looks the likeliest area to cause problems that might stop the script without even throwing a php error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it´s a character/encoding error, open both files with notepad++ , goto Encoding, then select Convert to UTF-8, save the file and test it again.

Good Luck!